# Where should I put common functionality for the group of similar classes?

Tags: c#, oop

Suppose I have a library with following class hierarchy:

```
interface IDevice 
{
    void Connect(DeviceAdderss address);
    void Disconnect();
}

public abstract DeviceBase : IDevice
{
    // IDevice implementation plus other stuff
}

public DeviceA : DeviceBase
{
    // Some device A specific stuff
}

public DeviceB : DeviceBase
{
    // Some device B specific stuff 
}
```

Now I want to use this library in my WPF application. For example I need to add some commands (ICommand objects: RelayCommand or whatever) to every device. Also I'd like to use all devices from WPF app in the same manner (i.e. they all have to implement same interface or have same base class).

So the question is: **where should I put that additional "wpf" functionality?**

I can see 2 possible approaches:

1) Put this functionality to IDevice or DeviceBase - but I don't like this because the library could be used in different applications (winforms, console etc.), so it would be unwanted in some cases.

2) Create "wrapper" classes in my WPF app, something like this:

```
class DeviceWrapper<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
  where T : DeviceBase
{
    public T Device { .. }
    public ICommand ConnectCommand { .. }
    public ICommand DisconnectCommand { .. }
    //... other stuff
}
```

This approach looks better, but in this case I have to create too many similar wrappers (if devices have some slight differences from each other)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the shared functionality is not needed by all devices that inherit from DeviceBase, group the extra functionality by responsibility into interfaces and implement those interfaces on a case-by-case basis only on the devices that require them.

Comment: Thanks, but shared functionality is needed by all devices with only small changes from device to device.

Comment: ok in that case, I would follow your approach 2 and create Wpf specific device classes internal to the Wpf application, and not the code library, that extend the functionality of standard devices class with functionality needed only for the Wpf application.